# How to add "button" within "anchor" tag - each one active with different purpose

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've designed a layout like the following:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| Product Name 1              [add to cart] |
|  Product brief                            |
+-------------------------------------------+
| Product Name 2              [add to cart] |
|  Product brief                            |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

The thing is done like the following (*simplified*):

```
<a href="/product-url">
   <span class="left">
      <h4>Product Name</h4>
      <p>Product Brief</p>
   </span>
   <span class="right>
     <input type="button" id="prod-id" value="add to cart">
   </span>
</a>
```

I want the whole product block to be activated to be anchored to the product, and that's why I embraced with an anchor tag. But I also need the "add to cart" button to be activated, whenever clicked. But the first anchor tag doesn't let the cart button to be active. I tried z-index, but failed.

I tried embracing with `<div>` instead of anchor tag with JavaScript redirect, but the same happened, and that's why I get back to the anchor tag embracing.

I want:

- The anchor tag to let the user get into the Product
- The add to cart button (within the anchor tag) to let the user add the product to the cart

Comment: Just an FYI: `<p>` is [not a valid child](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) of `<span>`. `<span>` expects "Phrasing Content" inside of it. It would be more appropriate to use another `<span>` element there instead of a `<p>` element, anyway.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what "anchor" means in this context.

Comment: And the same with `a` and `input` – an `a` element is not allowed to have “interactive content”, which an input field is. You will have to place your input element _outside_ of the link, and then _position_ it over it using CSS.

Comment: clicking the input inside your `<a>` would count as a click ON the `<a>` and start taking you to the new href.

Comment: Thanks to CBroe, and MarcB for understanding my Cause. Thanks to TylerH for the lesson - I'm going for that. BTW, I think even a wrong question should have an answer - an answer with right direction, because with that answer the common misunderstanding will be gone. Hate to those with the down votes (with full respect to the community)

Answer (score 0):

You could submit the add to cart form with the button and redirect to the product page once completed/ In older browsers especially mixing an  with a  does not work as one would intend.

Comment: Sorry, that concept is wrong. I want the anchor and the button should work independently.